# Can't map types using a generic function using react.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a Next.js project and currently stuck with TypeScript error.

I have 2 forms: RegisterForm and LoginForm with useState hook call in each. Below are listed state definitions for LoginForm and RegisterForm as follows.

```
interface LoginFormState {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirm: string;
}

interface RegisterFormState extends LoginFormState {
  username: string;
}
```

As you can see the only difference between them is "username" field in RegisterFormState.
For example useState call in RegisterForm looks like this:

```
const [{ email, password, passwordConfirm, username }, setFormState] =
    useState<RegisterFormState>({
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      passwordConfirm: '',
    });
```

In LoginForm it's almost the same, but without 'username' field.

I have a generic function handleFormChange which updates form's state when a user types characters in the input fields.

```
export const handleFormChange = <T>(
  inputValue: string,
  key: keyof T,
  setFormState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>
) => {
  setFormState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [key]: inputValue,
  }));
};
```

So as to not copy myself I created reusable FormControl component which looks like this:

```
interface Props {
  value: string;
  stateFieldToChange: keyof RegisterFormState; // !
  labelValue: string;
  setFromState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<RegisterFormState>>; //!
}

const FormControl: FC<Props> = ({
  value,
  stateFieldToChange,
  labelValue,
  setFromState,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="mb-6">
      <label
        className="block text-lg mb-2 font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"
        htmlFor={stateFieldToChange}
      >
        {labelValue}
      </label>
      <input
        className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 px-4 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 lg:text-lg sm:text-sm sm:leading-6 dark:text-white dark:bg-light-black"
        type={
          stateFieldToChange === 'passwordConfirm'
            ? 'password'
            : stateFieldToChange
        }
        name={stateFieldToChange}
        id={stateFieldToChange}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleFormChange(
            e.currentTarget.value,
            stateFieldToChange,
            setFromState
          );
        }}
        required
        placeholder="Enter your email..."
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I correctly choose the type in FormControl Props so that it won't give me errors that LoginFormState dosen't have 'username' field in it? Or when I use it in LoginForm it says that it's missing "username" field.

I have tried to create a mixed type, where field 'username' is optional, but still it gives me errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add generic to your `Props` interface:

```
interface Props<T extends RegisterFormState | LoginFormState> {
  value: string;
  stateFieldToChange: keyof T;
  labelValue: string;
  setFromState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>;
}
```

And update your component like this:

```
const FormControl = <T extends RegisterFormState | LoginFormState>({
  value,
  stateFieldToChange,
  labelValue,
  setFromState,
}: Props<T>) => {/* Same code as in your post */};
```

Later in code you can use component as you would do normally:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState<RegisterFormState>({email: '', password: '', passwordConfirm: '', username: ''});

  return (<FormControl value={formState.username} labelValue="Username" setFromState={setFormState} stateFieldToChange='username'  />)
};

const Form2 = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState<LoginFormState>({email: '', password: '', passwordConfirm: ''});

  return (<FormControl value={formState.email} labelValue="Email" setFromState={setFormState} stateFieldToChange='email'  />)
};
```

In cases when TypeScript won't be able to deduct generic from usage, you can also provide in explicitly:

```
<FormControl<RegisterFormState> prop1="blah" prop2="blah" />
```